# Windows knows IP address of a host, and at the same time doesn't know it

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I have a DNS server in my home network. Most of the time, Windows 10 (fully up to date) uses this DNS server and has no problem resolving names. Occasionally though, I get this problem:

```
C:\Users\bbausch>ping jupiter.home
Ping request could not find host jupiter.home. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\bbausch>nslookup jupiter.home
Server:  homeserver.home
Address:  192.168.1.16

Name:    jupiter.home
Address:  192.168.1.27
```

In this case, it looks like Windows doesn't use DNS when pinging (and pretty much any other attempt to access home network hosts, such as ssh). Access to IP addresses works as expected.

Usually, this goes away after a few minutes or hours. I have not been able to correlate the problem or its disappearance with anything.

**What can I do to force Windows to always use my DNS server?**

---

**Additional information:** It just happened again. I managed to launch Wireshark, tracing packets for UDP port 53 and 5353. No packets. Next time I will try TCP.

On the other hand, the command `ipconfig /flushdns` seems to have solved the problem (or it went away on its own). This command is supposed to clear the DNS client cache, although I noticed that a few old records still remain. I also found how to disable the client cache in the registry.

Comment: Could you show the results of `nslookup -q=AAAA jupiter.home`? Are there any related records in `ipconfig /displaydns`?

Comment: While I was writing my question, the error went away. Still, I am adding the output of these two commands. Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to check the same `ipconfig /displaydns` while the problem is still present, to see if Windows has somehow cached a negative response... (The point of nslookup actually wasn't to check whether IPv6 _addresses_ are present or not, but whether your server returns the correct response to AAAA queries if they're _not_ present. The expected response (like you have) is a "successful" reply with 0 addresses, but some cheap DNS servers – ones found in home routers, typically – instead return a "no such domain" error, making the OS think the name as a whole doesn't exist.)

Comment: Thanks. I do have a dubious home router that came with my internet connection, but I use my own BIND-based DNS. Unfortunately, the problem refuses to surface; I have to wait.

Comment: Well, whenever it does, start up Wireshark and see exactly what Windows is looking for.

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure what to filter for. There is too much activity on my network to go through all packets.

Comment: Start with a display filter `dns` or `(udp.port == 53 || tcp.port == 53)` to see just DNS packets, or maybe `dns || llmnr || mdns || nbns` to cover all the name lookup protocols. (Normally even with Wireshark, the machine shouldn't be receiving all activity on your network -- only packets belonging to the machine itself, and a few odd broadcasts here and there.)

Comment: It happened again. I added to the question.